# Firebase: Not all images listed in firebase console

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-console

I'm uploading images in Firebase and it's working great.

However, when I look at the Firebase console folder where the images are stored only a couple image are listed even though there should be more.

On each image upload, I'm getting a successful callback and a 'downloadURL' that I can use to view the image. Which is great!

But then in the fb console only a few of these images are showing. Here for example there are three files listed, but there should be 10+.

[image]

I'm kind of at a loss of what might be going on here. Any ideas?

Comment: are you uploading images one at a time, or together at once ? it may seem trivial, but i do recall having the same issue with drive when i uploaded multiple files at once.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Nope, just one at a time. Mobile camera upload.

Comment: For me, not only image files but folders as well. I have some folders created on my local firebase project folder under `public` folder (same level as those folders appear on the Firebase Storage console), but after running `firebase deploy`, everything is accessible and working fine except not appearing on the Firebase Storage console. I would like to know the answer too.